# Question in how scanf_s detect characters in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to understand how these typed codes affect the result. The function is `fscanf_s`.

There are 3 things I don't understand.

1. At line 11 and 12, in between `&c1`, `&c2`, and `&c3`, certain numbers are typed in. Deleting those numbers would cause `out.txt` to print empty space. I have no clue why numbers between are necessary.
2. At line 11, `%3c` is placed and `c2` for `fprintf` at line 13 just gives an empty space. I have no idea what `%3c` means here. As far as I know the term should be referring to accepting three characters, but it seems like that is not the case here.
3. At line 12, `%%` is placed, resulting only `c4` to be changed. I understand that it might be `%%` stops the scanning process but I am not too sure about that. Didn't `fscanf_s` acknowledge that after `%%`, it has to scan one more `%c`?

I know that `fscanf_s` shows similar behavior as `scanf_s` but knowing them didn't quite get me an answer.

```
char c1 = 'a', c2 = 'b', c3 = 'c', c4 = 'd', c5 = 'e', c6 = 'g';

int i, j;
FILE* infile, * outfile;
fopen_s(&infile, "data.txt", "r");
fopen_s(&outfile, "out.txt", "w");

i = fscanf_s(infile, "%c%3c%c", &c1, 1, &c2, 1, &c3, 1); //this line 11
j = fscanf_s(infile, "%c %% %c", &c4, 1, &c5, 1, &c6, 1);//and this line 12
fprintf(outfile, "%c%c%c: (%d)\n", c1, c2, c3, i);
fprintf(outfile, "%c%c%c: (%d)\n", c4, c5, c6, j);
```

data.txt prints below:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
```

out.txt prints below:

```
A c: (1)
Deg: (1)
```

Comment: I hope someone isn't actually teaching you to use `fopen_s()`/`fscanf_s()`.  Those are non-portable, optional extensions to C that Microsoft didn't even create per the C standard Annex K.  Read this:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm  "... the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1 ...  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Comment: These are some of the codes my professor gave to me. He mainly focuses on what is printed if some deviations are made in the source regardless of the usefulness or the validity. So...here I am.

Comment: Your professor gave you nothing else?

Comment: Will you please match the line numbers to the code? Are there 3 lines missing? If so, why?

Comment: "I have no clue why numbers between are necessary." Your first port of call in understanding a function should be its man page. The page for [`fscanf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fscanf-s-fscanf-s-l-fwscanf-s-fwscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017) states:  *"Unlike `fscanf` ... `fscanf_s` ... requires the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable."*

Comment: You forgot to show us the content of `data.txt`

Comment: @AndrewHenle nothing else

Comment: @WeatherVane I just noticed it and wrote down the number. Thanks.

Comment: @Gerhardh I just added data.txt. Thanks!

Comment: Your next task is to understand what the return value from the `scanf` function family means. It was `1` for each of your calls (`i` and `j`). Why was that? Why wasn't it `3` for each call? The best way to understand the behaviour is hands-on: experimenting will tell you more than staring at the node.

Comment: Lokk in [tag:tr24731] if you want to know why Annex K is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mind searching information on CppReference. [This single page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) gave me many information on the answer you are asking here. Though, I must admit some behaviours still aren't obvious but I hope I will be able to help you to understand better what's happening in your code.

1. > `fscanf_s` is same as [`fscanf`], except that `%c`, `%s`, and `%[` conversion specifiers each expect two arguments (the usual pointer and a value of type `rsize_t` indicating the size of the receiving array, which may be 1 when reading with a %c into a single `char`)". (source : the [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) above)

   Alright, there you found where your additional numbers come from. They are just numbers which specify the number of characters you will receive, which have to be one for a `char`.

---

2. > Following errors are detected at runtime and call the currently installed [constraint handler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/set_constraint_handler_s) function: [...] The number of characters that would be written by `%c`, `%s`, or `%[`, plus the terminating null character, would exceed the second (rsize_t) argument provided for each of those conversion specifiers (source : the [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) above)

   This means that when using `%3c` but with the parameters `&c2, 1` you try to get 3 characters from your file but want only one in c2... Which should result in an error handled by the [constraint handler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/set_constraint_handler_s) function and your call in line 11 should return EOF. I must admit I'm still a bit confused with the behaviour you get (function call returns 1) but there is definitely something wrong with the usage of `%3c` with parameters `&c2, 1`.

---

3. > `%%` matches literal % (source: the [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) above)

   The usage of `%%` seems to force `fscanf_s` to find a `%` character within infile. As it don't see any, it just go through your file, reach `EOF` and the function end without modifing `c5` and `c6`.

Comment: This was such a big help. After reading your answer, I find my questions pretty dumb. (Although I still don't get the %3c part precisely) Thanks for the tip. That page would be useful for the remaining questions I have.